# Get records from previous year who has no record this year

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a monitoring system. Now, I want to get the records from previous year who has no record this year(one table only). How would I do that? Student here :)

sample_tbl

```
Id  name    date
1   John    2015
2   Anne    2015
3   John    2016
```

expected output

```
Id  name    date
2   Anne    2015
```

Comment: One way would be to self join your table on the year/previous year, and retain records for which the current year is null.  But unfortunately I cannot give you a query because you provided no details whatsoever.

Comment: Instead of an image of a text table, please copy/paste the plain text table above into your question. Use the `{}` editor toolbar button or `ctl-k` to format it as a code block. This allows potential answers to quickly import your tables for testing and demonstration queries.

Comment: another way, for each person [group], if the year is in (2015,2016) [where], but the count of distinct years is 1 [having] then there is a missing year.

Comment: That might not be applicable. John might have records for 2014,2013,2012,etc.